# Relation between ExectuorService and CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, executorservice, completable-future

I am learning multithreading and am now confused about one topic i.e ExecutorService and CompletableFuture.

Let me summarise that what I learnt till now.

ExecutorService is a Java High-level thread API, which helps in managing threads, i.e two independent threads which is doing their task. But still, if threads are dependent then we can use producer-consumer patterns and many more.
This helps in achieving concurrency. Since multiple threads can be used for running a multiple tasks.

But In CompletableFuture, which we called async programming/ Reactive programming, is also used for accomplishing the same task. i.e It can also run multiple threads.

But I don't get the point of when to use which one and how they are different from each other? What are there use cases in which they sit perfectly?

Comment: `ExecutorService ... helps in managing tasks`  Threads, not tasks.

Comment: `Since multiple threads can be used for running a task.`  This isn't right either.  I think I'm seeing a pattern of referring to "task" as the broad outline of something to accomplish.  Normally in concurrency a "task" is defined narrowly as something (like a method) that can be executed by exactly one thread.  A task is basically the smallest unit of code that can be executed.  You might be using a different definition but on this subject "task" is going to get confusing for other people because it normally means something specific.

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I wrote the tasks instead of the thread. Now I have edited the post.
@markspace, can you help me to get me out of this confused state in which am i?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CompletableFuture is, in essence, a mechanism by which one thread can find out when another thread has finished doing something.

So, a typical model is this kind of method:

```
 CompletableFuture<Result> doSomething() {
      CompletableFuture<Result> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        ... arrange to do work in some other thread ...
      return future;
 }
```

The caller of doSomething() gets back an object which it can use to determine completion, wait for completion, get the Result of doing 'something', and perhaps run some other work using the Result.

So, how does doSomething() arrange to do work in some other thread.  Well, one way is to execute the work vis some ExecutorService.  Though there are plenty of other ways to go about it.  Regardless, when the work is complete, it will call `future.complete(someResult)` to set the CompletableFuture into 'completed' state with the expected Result.

Maybe you're confused because our caller could write

```
doSomething().thenAcceptAsync((result) -> blahBlah(result));
```

In this case, doSomething() proceeds as above. When that is complete, we want to run another operation, also asynchronously.  Because we used theAcceptAsync, this work will be handled via an ExecutorService known to the CompletableFuture framework (the common ForkJoinPool, to be exact - this is documented).

Summary - this is not 'choose one or the other'.  ExecutorServices provide the means to run units of work in other threads.  CompletableFutures provide the means to know and react to completion of those units of work.

Comment: In real scenarios, What do we return from CompletableFuture? Is it Join() result or CompletableFuture and then it is up to the client that How he wants to consume it?
What is the best practise?

Comment: It's the result of the operation.   If a synchronous operation were to return an object of some type, which I termed 'Result' in my answer, then the equivalent async operation can return a CompletableFuture<Result>, which you can understand as a placeholder for a Result that will become available some time in the future.  (IMO talking about joins and so on is a loss of encapsulation; as a caller you don't need to know what goes on inside the "...arrange to do work..." part, that's implementation).

Comment: But sure, the client has latitude on what he does before and after the Result becomes available.   He can just wait for it: `r = future.get()`, or indicate that he'd like an action later: `future.whenComplete(this::handler)`.  Or execute the next in a chain of async actions: `future.thenAcceptAsync(...)`.  There's a fairly rich structure of supporting operations.  What the caller chooses to do  is not the concern of the initial operation (doSomething in my example).